# Error when installing Android apk on device

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I have this strange error when installing apk on device, from Eclipse. The console gives error message: Failed to install, but in fact the file is installed.

Also, the application doesn't start after the installation, I have to do it manually.

I have done the this same procedure over and over again, without problems, but now the error occurs.

Thanks!

Comment: Which device (model, etc.)? It's a real device, not emulator (virtual device)? Did you have the app installed before? Or is it the first time you install it on that device?

Comment: Have you turned the device on and off again? (Seriously!)

Comment: Matt, thanks for the advice! After turning the device on and off it worked again!...

Comment: Do what @MattGibson suggested and also try to uninstall the previous app completely before installing it again...

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've posted my advice as an answer, you never know, it might help future people with the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that sometimes a device gets stuck in a strange state, and no matter what you do will give odd errors on install. Turning the device itself on and off again usually cures the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ADB work normally when issued from command prompt? Try installing any apk manually using

```
adb install <filename.apk>
```

and see what is being returned. It may be an issue with the return from adb not being correctly recognized by eclipse. I'll also suggest changing the USB port to check if the same issue is occurring.

Comment: Thank you i5h4n. It is now working again, thanks to the advice of Matt.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the app on the device before installing the new apk...